# Как подключить 2-й выделенный IP

Tags: linux, apache, сервер, ip, vds

Приветствую, есть VDS и 2 выделенных IP, один давали с покупкой VDS (и сейчас доступ по нём открыт), а 2-й купил дополнительно.

Как мне подключить 2-й IP адрес к этому VDS, что бы при запросе на него открывались файлы, к примеру, из директории `/var/www/site2/` не подключая к доменам? 
И доступ к директориям должен быть непосредственно по IP.

Спасибо.

Comment: просто не указывайте имя сервера в соответствующем блоке `virtualhost`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно назначить этот IP вашем сетевому интерфейсу. Как это делается - зависит от дистрибутива. Это либо файл /etc/network/interfaces для Debian/Ubuntu, либо /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* для CentOS/Fedora. Вы же знаете какая у вас ОС? Посмотрите её документацию.

Далее вам нужно сказать про этот IP веб-серверу. Если в директории `Listen` не указан конкретный IP - то Apache слушает все имеющиеся адреса. Если вас это устраивает - оставляйте, в противном случае впишите лишь новый адрес, если вы хотите что бы обращения принимались лишь на него. Далее - у вас уже есть `VirtualHost` который настроен на директорию /var/www/site2/ или нет? Если нет, создайте его, указав примерно такое:

```
<VirtualHost <новый_IP>>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/site2/"
<остальные_директивы_по_вкусу>
</VirtualHost>
```

В конце не забудьте применить новую конфигурацию.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, вам нужен [виртуальный хост, привязанный к IP](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html). В конфигурации Apache httpd добавляете раздел

`<VirtualHost ваш_второй_ip:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site2/"
    ServerName www1.example.com
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/www1/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/www1/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>`

Разумеется, подправив адреса и имена файлов в соответствии с вашими.